# How do I simulate the screenshot function (Mac) Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, simulation

Here is my current code that DOES NOT work:

```
CGEventSourceRef src =
CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStateHIDSystemState);

CGEventRef cmdd = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(src, 0x37, true);
CGEventRef cmdu = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(src, 0x37, false);
CGEventRef optd = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(src, 0x3A, true);
CGEventRef optu = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(src, 0x3A, false);
CGEventRef dd = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(src, 0x02, true);
CGEventRef du = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(src, 0x02, false);

CGEventSetFlags(dd, kCGEventFlagMaskCommand ^ kCGEventFlagMaskAlternate);
CGEventSetFlags(du, kCGEventFlagMaskCommand ^ kCGEventFlagMaskAlternate);


CGEventTapLocation loc = kCGHIDEventTap; // kCGSessionEventTap also works
CGEventPost(loc, cmdd); //Cmd down
CGEventPost(loc, optd); //Option down
CGEventPost(loc, dd);   //D down
CGEventPost(loc, cmdu); //Cmd up
CGEventPost(loc, optu); //Option up
CGEventPost(loc, du);   //D up

CFRelease(cmdd);
CFRelease(cmdu);
CFRelease(optd);
CFRelease(optu);
CFRelease(dd);
CFRelease(du);
CFRelease(src);
```

What do I need to change to make it work? Does anyone know why it fails to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I managed to solve my issue**

Here is how I did it:

1. I made a shell script file that executed the command "screencapture -s /temp/tempscr/png"
2. I then copied the .sh file into my "Supporting Files" folder within my app
3. I then executed the following code:

   ```
   NSString *path = @"/Applications/CloudSyncMac.app/Contents/Resources/screencapture.sh";
   NSArray *args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nil, nil];
   [[NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:path arguments:args] waitUntilExit];
   ```
4. It works!!!

Answer (score 2):

I cant fathom why you want to take a a screenshot by emulating the key commands to do it (which can be changed btw so its fragile). it is far better in every way to simply do this programmatically. Apple has [example code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/ScreenSnapshot/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011158) to this, and the [Quartz Display Services documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/ScreenSnapshot/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011158) can help you beyond that.

Comment: I have been trying to do that and people say it is not possible, haha! I originally wanted to do it programatically. Thanks!

Comment: The example only allows a full screen capture and I would like to use the UI function to select a region. Is this also possible?

Comment: Instead of `CGDisplayCreateImage()`, use `CGDisplayCreateImageForRect(). You can use your own UI to let the user select the rect (a transparent overlay window where you draw a semi-transparent selection rectangle).

Comment: @CloudSync even without the existence of `CGDisplayCreateImageForRect()`, you could easily take a full screen shot and trim it down based on the selection rectangle that triggered the shot. You don't always need an *exact* function match to achieve your goals.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the 'screencapture' command-line tool - the man page is here:
[man screencapture](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/screencapture.1.html)

This is available from at least 10.6 and will save you having to code the logic yourself.

For example doing 'screencapture -s ~/Desktop/screenshot.png' in Terminal will run a region-based screen capture and place the output in 'screenshot.png' on your desktop.

You can call the command-line tool using the C library 'system()' function.