# Taking a screenshot of user defined area in swift macOS

Tags: swift, cocoa, screenshot

I am developing a macOS app which requires the user to select an area of the screen and then the area(screenshot) is converted to an image.

Right now I can’t seem to find a way to let the user draw the rectangle which allows the user to select the region of which to take the screenshot.

Although there are a lot of sources stating how to take screenshot on iOS, the same can’t be said for macOS.

[image]

Comment: Ask not what a screenshot can do for you.  Ask what you can do for `CGWindowListCreateImage`.  And you need to clip an area for yourself.

Comment: See [For macOS Cocoa, how do I specify a window or a rectangle on the screen for taking a screenshot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61731812), [How to draw rectangle like the screen shot selection on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27377188), [How do I simulate the screenshot function (Mac) Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25835621) and [Drawing selection box (rubberbanding, marching ants) in Cocoa, ObjectiveC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357960)